# Is VSTO runtime installed with MS Office installation?

Tags: vsto

I want to build an add-in for Office applications using VSTO. I want to know if the VSTO runtime is installed along with the installation of MS Office 2007 or not. If Office installation does not install VSTO runtime then I will have to make my setups do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, VSTO is not installed by default. Add it as a pre-requisite to ClickOnce or your setup project.